# REST-EJB AccessLocalException causes BadRequest(500) instead of Unauthorized(401)

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, jersey, ejb

I get the exception:

```
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[org.netbeans.rest.application.config.ApplicationConfig]: Servlet.service() for servlet org.netbeans.rest.application.config.ApplicationConfig threw exception
javax.ejb.AccessLocalException: Client not authorized for this invocation
```

This is perfectly normal, as it is not authorized for this methodcall.

Onfortunately, as this EJB is a REST Service as well, it throws a "500 - Bad Request" http status. Instead I would like to have a "401 - Unauthorized".

Should I not use EJB Security or should I catch this AccessLocalException in the ApplicationConfig or should I use Jersey to implement REST Security?

Roles are defined in the web.xml and annotations are put upon the EJB Bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define an ExceptionMapper, that maps a General Exception onto a HTTP Response.

```
import javax.ejb.EJBAccessException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class EJBAccessExceptionMapper implements
        ExceptionMapper<EJBAccessException>
{
  @Override
  public Response toResponse(EJBAccessException exception)
  {
    return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that when returning a 401 the HTTP spec requires that the response MUST include a WWW-Authenticate header field.  https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.2